# Java - Correct way of add a ConcurrentHashMap to a JList?

Tags: java, thread-safety, jlist

Here is my example code:

Person Class:

```
public class Person {



private String firstName;
private String lastName;



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    return true;
}



public Person(String firstName,String lastName){

    this.setFirstName(firstName);
    this.setLastName(lastName);
}



public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}



private void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}



public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}



private void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

Test/Main:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Person> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person>();
    storage.put(1, new Person("Sally","Solomon"));
    storage.put(2, new Person("Harry","Solomon"));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Button");


    Person [] personArr= storage.values().toArray(new Person[0]);
    String [] names = new String[personArr.length];

    System.out.println(personArr.length);

    for(int i=0; i<personArr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(personArr[i].getFirstName());
        names[i] = personArr[i].getFirstName() + " " + personArr[i].getLastName();
    }



    final JList jList1 = new JList(names);
```

**Question:**
What is the correct way of taking the values in a ConcurrectHashMap and adding them to a JList? The way I've done it, is read all the values into a string array and add that to the JList.

1. Can it be done more efficiently?
2. Is their a tread-safe way of doing it? Or do I just update the storage and add that to the JList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [ConcurrentHashMap's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

So if you are the only one iterating over the map, you're good, even if another thread is updating it. But note that when using Swing, thread safety is mentioned mostly when accessing the GUI widgets - it must be done from the Event Dispatch Thread.
So your code above should be run from a runnable passed to [EventQueue#invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Thanks. How exactly would I run the  EventQueue#invokeLater? Forgive me, I'm just a beginner to Java.

Comment: EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourCodeHere
            }
        } );

Comment: Just for clarification what code would I place in the yourCodeHere part?

Comment: Your entire test/main. Or at least from the part that starts with JFRAME... on.